# Zero space between rows in tabularx

Tags: spacing, graphics, tabularx, rows

Say that you have this code in the preamble to get your pictures of different sizes centered (vertically and horizontally) in a tabularx environment (the pictures are included with \includegraphics in each cell):

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

How could you manage to make the space between rows null?

Here is an MWE of the problem:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,demo]{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}CCC@{}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.03]{example-image-a}};
\node[fill=white,draw=black,anchor=north west,below right=0.2cm and 0.2cm of figure.north west] {1};
\end{tikzpicture}

    &
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.03]{example-image-b}};
\node[fill=white,draw=black,anchor=north west,below right=0.2cm and 0.2cm of figure.north west] {2};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
    &

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.05]{example-image-c}};
\node[fill=white,draw=black,anchor=north west,below right=0.2cm and 0.2cm of figure.north west] {3};
\end{tikzpicture}


    \\


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.03]{example-image-d}};
\node[fill=white,draw=black,anchor=north west,below right=0.2cm and 0.2cm of figure.north west] {4};
\end{tikzpicture}

    &
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.03]{example-image-e}};
\node[fill=white,draw=black,anchor=north west,below right=0.2cm and 0.2cm of figure.north west] {5};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
    &

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.7,width=0.03]{example-image-f}};
\node[fill=white,draw=black,anchor=north west,below right=0.2cm and 0.2cm of figure.north west] {6};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}\FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Erm... it's *you* that should post an MWE, so that we can understand your problem. 

Comment: @Rmano sorry, I wrote one in the question's body.

Comment: With "null" do you mean the `tikzpicture`s should touch?

Comment: @Skillmon yes, or they should be a close distance that I can define

Comment: @el_maxx start by removing all the blank lines inside of your table's body. Those are implicit `\par` tokens and add vertical space inside of your `C` column type.

Comment: You can use `tabularray` package with `X[c,m]` columntype and set `rowsep`.

Comment: How or where is the `C` column type defined?

Comment: @Mico Sorry. I just edited it in the question's body.

Comment: tabularx is just making things slow here, it does multiple trial settings to get the best column widths for linebreakingvtext within a column but there is no linebreakingvand you know in advance how wide you want the columns

Comment: Vertical space nool? You men that pictures in the first row tach to image in the second row?

Comment: also please fix your example so that people can run it to see the problem do not use images only you have, you could use example-image and adjust the scale to show your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I've understood your formatting objective. Something like the following, maybe? Note the complete absence of a `tabularx` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,demo]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[angle=-90,width=0.31\linewidth]{images/taller_1.jpeg}};%
\node[fill=white,draw=black,anchor=north west,below right=2mm and 2mm of figure.north west]{1};%
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill    
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[angle=-90,width=0.31\linewidth]{images/taller_2.jpeg}};%
\node[fill=white,draw=black,anchor=north west,below right=2mm and 2mm of figure.north west]{2};%
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[angle=-90,width=0.31\linewidth]{images/taller_3.jpeg}};%
\node[fill=white,draw=black,anchor=north west,below right=2mm and 2mm of figure.north west]{3};%
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[angle=-90,width=0.31\linewidth]{images/taller_4.jpeg}};%
\node[fill=white,draw=black,anchor=north west,below right=2mm and 2mm of figure.north west]{4};%
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[angle=-90,width=0.31\linewidth]{images/taller_5.jpeg}};%
\node[fill=white,draw=black,anchor=north west,below right=2mm and 2mm of figure.north west]{5};%
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node (figure) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[angle=-90,width=0.31\linewidth]{images/taller_6.jpeg}};%
\node[fill=white,draw=black,anchor=north west,below right=2mm and 2mm of figure.north west]{6};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does happen if one of the figures has a different size? That's why I use tabular/x environment (middle alignment).

Comment: @el_maxx - Please note the setting `width=0.31\linewidth` for all six images. There's no need to shoehorn the images into a 3-column tabularx environment.

Comment: Ok. Besides your example, is there a way to middle (vertical) align the tikzpictures in a figure environment?

Comment: @el_maxx - vertical centering is the default.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

To long for the comment ...
It is not clear (at least to me), what is your problem. By wee bit rewritten your MWE gives the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,demo]{report}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\setkeys{Gin}{angle=-90,width=\linewidth}
\tikzset{
N/.style = {draw, fill=white,anchor=north west,
            below right=0.2cm and 0.2cm of figure.north west}
        }\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}CCC@{}}
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (figure) {\includegraphics{images/taller_1.jpeg}};
\node[N] {1};
\end{tikzpicture}
    &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (figure) {\includegraphics{images/taller_2.jpeg}};
\node[N] {2};
\end{tikzpicture}
    &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (figure) {\includegraphics{images/taller_3.jpeg}};
\node[N] {3};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \hline
   \\

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (figure) {\includegraphics{images/taller_4.jpeg}};
\node[N] {4};
\end{tikzpicture}
    &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (figure) {\includegraphics{images/taller_5.jpeg}};
\node[N] {5};
\end{tikzpicture}
    &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (figure) {\includegraphics{images/taller_6.jpeg}};
\node[N] {6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Does bottom of image in the first row should touch to top of images in the second row?

**Edit:**   From your comment can be concluded that you after following:

[image]

Quite unusual request, but can be done relatively easily by use of the `tabularray`package. Its `X` column options `c` and `m` centered cells' contents horizontally and vertically respectively:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,demo]{report}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
\setkeys{Gin}{angle=-90,width=\linewidth}
\tikzset{
M/.style = {inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
N/.style = {draw, fill=white,anchor=north west,
            below right=0.2cm and 0.2cm of figure.north west}
        }
\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} *{3}{X[c,m]} @{}},
             rowsep=-4.4pt}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[M] (figure) {\includegraphics{images/taller_1.jpeg}};
\node[N] {1};
\end{tikzpicture}
    &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[M] (figure) {\includegraphics{images/taller_2.jpeg}};
\node[N] {2};
\end{tikzpicture}
    &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[M] (figure) {\includegraphics{images/taller_3.jpeg}};
\node[N] {3};
\end{tikzpicture}   \\
%    \vspace{-8pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[M] (figure) {\includegraphics{images/taller_4.jpeg}};
\node[N] {4};
\end{tikzpicture}
    &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[M] (figure) {\includegraphics{images/taller_5.jpeg}};
\node[N] {5};
\end{tikzpicture}
    &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[M] (figure) {\includegraphics{images/taller_6.jpeg}};
\node[N] {6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```